# Online Synopsis of each Mesechta of Talmud Bavli

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, talmud-bavli, english

Where can I find an online synopsis of each Mesechta of Talmud Bavli?

Details:

1. I do not care so much about length, the longer the better. As long as it is not *too* long.
2. I want a overall summary of the topics. For example:

   > Mesechta Makkos deals with 3 main subjects: Aydim Zomimim (Perek 1), Golus (Perek 2), and Malkus (Perek 3) etc.

I think you understand what I want.

Comment: Your synopsis of _Makos_ is certainly not three pages! Does it really satisfy your criterion of "the longer the better"?

Comment: 1. Makkos is very short and simple to summarize 2. And it could be more explained, I just made a kitzur of the kitzur.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Soncino has an introduction to a) The Talmud, b) Each Order, c) Each Tractate.

You can see most of them here: http://halakhah.com/

Comment: They do not have a introduction for all of them.

Answer (score 6):

Look at the introduction of the מאירי to each masechta, where he breaks down the topics of the masechta in general as well as perek by perek.
(He also does that in a more perek-specific manner at the beginning of each perek.)

While not usually online, the [Hebrewbooks website](http://hebrewbooks.org/) has the בית הבחירה -- just search for "בית הבחירה."
[Here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40773&st=&pgnum=6) is an example of an introduction of the מאירי to a masechta; on that page, to בבא קמא.

Comment: look at new edit